# Displaying data in DataGridView without HorizontalScroll

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

My problem is data that load at startup in a DataGridView and a cell containing large data that I want to display on multiple lines instead of horizontalScroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple lines isn't (easily) supported. You can adjust the Width with Grid.AutoSizeColumnmode and the FillWidth properties of each column.

As an alternative Idea, why not place a multiline textbox near the Grid abd databind that to the specific column? Would show more of the text, but 1 row at a time.